# Get Max() rows per Revision Number in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this result set:

```
Company_ID | State | City | Rev |
Company 1  |  S-A  |  C-1 |  1  |
Company 2  |  S-B  |  C-2 |  1  |
Company 1  |  S-A  |  C-3 |  2  |
```

The result set that I wanted is

```
Company_ID | State | City | Rev |
Company 1  |  S-A  |  C-3 |  2  |
Company 2  |  S-B  |  C-2 |  1  |
```

Here's the query that I tried:

```
var list = (from coy in TBL_COMPANY
where coy.IsActive == "1"
select coy).ToList()
.Select(coy => new 
{
  coy.Company_ID,
  coy.State,
  coy.City,
  coy.Rev
});

var companyList = list.GroupBy (grp => new
{
   grp.Company_ID,
   grp.State,
   grp.City
})
.Select(cpy => new 
{
   CompanyID = cpy.Key.Company_ID,
   State = cpy.Key.State,
   City = cpy.Key.City,
   Rev = cpy.Max(c => c.Rev)
}).ToList();
```

However, I am not able to get the result set I wanted. My suspicion there is because of the `City` because it is included. However, I need these columns (except for the `Rev`). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "However, I am not able to do the result set I wanted." In what way? What *do* you get?

Comment: (It's not clear why you're grouping by company ID, state and city at all, to be honest. Is the company ID the effective key here, along with the revision?)

Comment: company id is the key that is used here. there's a rowid in that table, but per row has a different value.

Comment: and also it should be "get" not "do". sorry for the typo

Comment: You still haven't told us what the code you've provided actually *does* do though, or why you're grouping...

Comment: This will actually be a preparation to be joined with another list (employees)

Comment: That wasn't the answer to my question... *please* read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and try to understand how frustrating it is to try to help someone who won't answer the simple question of "Your code doesn't do what you want - what does it actually do?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required result doesn't fit you grouping. There are 3 different `City` items which should lead to 3 result items.

I'd say Jon Skeet's comment about Grouping **only** by `Company_ID` is correct.

Code (group by `Company_ID` and pick the items with the highest `Rev`):

```
var result = TBL_COMPANY.Where(x => x.IsActive == "1")
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Company_ID)
                        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Rev).First())
                        .Select(x=> new {x.Company_ID,  x.State,  x.City,  x.Rev})
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! Got what I needed.